# Does every increasing, super-linear function $f: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ with large image take a large set to a small set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ is an increasing function from the natural numbers to themselves which satisfies the following two properties:

- $f$ grows super-linearly: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{f(n)} = 0.$$
- The sum of the reciprocals of the values of $f$ diverges: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)} = \infty.$$

Call a subset $A$ of the integers *small* if $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ converges, and *large* if $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ diverges. Then the image $f(\Bbb{N}) = \{ f(n) \}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is a large set.

**Question: Under the above conditions on $f$, must there be a large set $A$ such that $f(A)$ is a small set? That is, does there exist a set $A \subset \Bbb{N}$ so that $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ diverges, but $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{f(a)}$ converges?**

My intuition is "yes" based on thinking about the example $f(n) = p_n$, the nth prime. For that function, letting $A$ be the set of all primes actually works: $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n} \text{ diverges but } \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(p_n)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_{p_n}} \text{ converges, }$$ since $p_n \approx n \log n$, so that we have $p_{p_n} \approx n (\log n)^2$. But there I have an explicit order of magnitude for $f(n)$ that I can use, and I think there should be an argument to show this even without reference to the specific function $f(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Recursively for every $k\in\Bbb N$, construct subsets $A_k$ of $\Bbb N$ as follows:

- Let $N(k)$ be such that $f(n) > k^2 n$ for all $n>N(k)$; without loss of generality we may assume that $N(k)$ is larger than all the integers in $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{k-1}$.
- Let $A_k$ be the set of integers between $N(k)$ and $2N(k)$. Then $\sum_{a\in A_k} \frac1a$ is approximately $\log 2$, while $\sum_{a\in A_k} \frac1{f(a)}$ is at most approximately $\frac1{k^2}\log 2$.

Then $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is a set with the desired properties.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!